# Undefined property: DOMElement::$wholeText

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm getting the following error: `Undefined property: DOMElement::$wholeText"` when I loop over the query and try to echo the wholeText result.

```
$try = $xpath->query('//h2/following-sibling::ul/li | //h2/following-sibling::h3/text()');

foreach($try as $values){
    echo $values->wholeText;    

    //echo '<pre>', print_r($values), '</pre>';
}
```

The `$xpath->query` returns the following when I `print_r` the `$values` variable from the foreach.

```
DOMText Object {
    [wholeText] => House Data
    [data] => House Data
    [length] => 10
    [nodeName] => #text
    [nodeValue] => House Data
    [nodeType] => 3
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => 
    [firstChild] => 
    [lastChild] => 
    [previousSibling] => 
    [nextSibling] => 
    [attributes] => 
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => 
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => House Data
)

DOMElement Object (
    [tagName] => li
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => li
    [nodeValue] => 12 doors are very expensive
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => 
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => li
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => 12 doors are very expensive
)

DOMText Object (
    [wholeText] => Car Data
    [data] => Car Data
    [length] => 8
    [nodeName] => #text
    [nodeValue] => Car Data
    [nodeType] => 3
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => 
    [firstChild] => 
    [lastChild] => 
    [previousSibling] => 
    [nextSibling] => 
    [attributes] => 
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => 
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => Car Data
)

DOMElement Object (
    [tagName] => li
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => li
    [nodeValue] => The car has 4 doors
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => 
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => li
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => The car has 4 doors
)
```

But if I `echo $values->nodeValue;` it works, although it echo's all of the data, I'm just trying to access the wholeText individually, I don't understand why this error is popping up?

**UPDATE:**

Now that I took a closer look, I see that when I `echo $values->wholeText;` it's trying to echo the DOMElement and not the DOMText.

How can I reference the DOMText instead of the DOMElement when echoing?

Comment: Why don't just put `text()` in the first part of your query? `//h2/following-sibling::ul/li/text()`

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks for replying. I can't do that because I just need the text from the h3, the data from the li's has html hyperlink tags that I need retrieved.

Comment: What about checking `textContent` then (instead of `wholeText`)? See, it's not clear what's the structure of XML: whether or not it'll be enough to go to `DOMElement->firstChild`.

Comment: @raina77ow, I thought about checking the textContent but it wouldn't have worked. I wound up checking the nodeType instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by checking the nodeType.

nodeType 1 is an element, 3 is text and so forth, you can find all the nodeTypes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp).

```
if($values->nodeType === 3){
    echo $values->textContent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing complicated: `wholeText` is a `DOMText` property, not a `DOMNode` property. When the part `//h2/following-sibling::ul/li` of your XPath query succeeds and returns a node that isn't a `DOMText` instance, you naturally obtain this error.

If you want to obtain the text inside the li element, using the convenient method `DOMNode::nodeValue` is a good way. Note that this method will also work with a `DOMText` instance since the `DOMText` class inherits from `DOMNode`.